# Connect to shared drive from Emacs on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, emacs, network-shares, cygwin, tramp

I am using emacs-w32.exe, invoked from Cygwin, on a Windows 7 machine. I'm trying to connect to a shared drive that I can otherwise access and write to (e.g., by using the Windows explorer), but I am unable to deduce the proper TRAMP (?) setup and invocation for the drive.

I've tried `C-x C-f` and then some variation of one of the following:

```
 \\REMOTE-HOST\<path>
 /plink:\\REMOTE-HOST:<path>
 /plink:USER@REMOTE-HOST:<path>
 /ssh:USER@REMOTE-HOST:<path>
```

... along with some other variations, mostly involving forward vs. back slashes.

I haven't yet installed a samba client, because I am on a Windows machine which natively connects to such a drive and it doesn't seem like it *should* be necessary, but if that's the answer, I don't know how to either (a) install a samba client from Cygwin, or (b) direct emacs-w32.exe to the proper path. But I'd hope that, between plink/PuTTY and the Windows native capacity, I shouldn't need to take such steps.

Any advice?

(EDIT: Steven's advice worked when I invoke `emacs`, but not `emacs-w32`, so I'll set that as the answer, but the mystery remains why the one works and not the other. But, pragmatically speaking, avoiding `emacs-w32` will work for me.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try forward slashes: `//REMOTE-HOST/<path>`

Comment: Tried that, and it thinks I'm trying to create //path/to/file on the local machine because I get the message: "Use M-x make-directory RET RET to create the directory and its parents."

Comment: `C-f C-x //serverName/shareName/file` works for me to open a remote file.  Tab completion even works.  This works in both emacs and emacs-w32.

Comment: Strange. Works for me with `emacs`, but not `emacs-w32`. Don't know why, but I'll avoid running the latter.